# Concatenate string with error

Tags: c, string, string-concatenation

I have this code in `C` but I don't know why I get an error like `Argument of type “char” is incompatible with parameter of type const char*`

```
char number_string[size] = { NULL };                
    int counter = 0;                                    

    for (counter = 0; counter < strlen(input_string - 1); counter++)
    {
        temp = input_string[counter];                   

        if (isdigit(temp))
        {
            strcat(number_string, temp); //temp variable has the error only in this line
        }
    }
```

Comment: `char number_string[size] = { NULL }; ` is not a valid declaration. It should be either `char *number_string =  NULL;` or `char number_string[size] = "mytext"; `. What is it for? If you want an empty string you could have, say, `char number_string[size] = "";`

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks. But the temp is still having an error.

Comment: @RigelKentCarbonel How is `temp` declared ?

Comment: the second argument of `strcat()` mus be a string, not a single character

Comment: You have not shown `temp`, but you can't use it `temp = input_string[counter];` *as well as* in `strcat(number_string, temp);`.In the first case it must be `int temp` or `char temp`, and in the second case (cat) it must be `char *temp` (a pointer, or array).

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt thank you. I just change the data type of temp from char to char *

Comment: Hmm, as other comments stated, now `temp = input_string[counter];` and `isdigit(temp)` should not compile anymore

Comment: I hope you have warnings enabled too, since `temp = input_string[counter];` won't work.

Comment: @RigelKentCarbonel  Instead of `strcat` you can do this - `number_string[strlen(number_string)]=temp;`

Comment: @WeatherVane will this work? `temp* = input_string[counter];`

Comment: @ameyCU don't forget to add a new NUL

Comment: `strlen(input_string - 1)` is wrong. You need to post a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that actually compiles without any errors or warnings (using `-Wall` with gcc or `-W4` with visual studio).

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt  I think if initialization to `'\0'` (_what he tries to do_) is done no need , **but if not then he need to do that manually.**

Comment: @RigelKentCarbonel I don't know if your suggestion will work, since you have not declared `temp` or made it clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @WeatherVane actually i declared the temp as `char *temp` will this work?

Comment: No: `temp* = input_string[counter];` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing `char` and `char *`. The declaration of `number_string[]` might not warn you, because `NULL` may simply be defined as `0`, which is legal as a char and as a pointer.  But the variable `temp` is definately a problem: You don't show its declaration, but its first assignment makes it a `char`, and its second use in `strcat` assumes it is a `char *`.

If you want to add a single character at a time to a string, you'll have to do it by hand, something like this:

```
int nslen = strlen(number_string);

for ...
    number_string[nslen++] = temp

number_string[nslen] = '\0';
```

Comment: Actually sir I declared my temp as `char`. Any solution to store the `temp` to `number_string[]`?

Comment: `strcpy(number_string, input_string);`

Comment: He only wants to add a character at a time to `number_string`...you'll just have to do that by hand. I'd create a variable `nl = 0` at the beginning, then where you want to add `temp`, do `number_string[nl++] = temp`. At the end, do `number_string[nl] = '\0'`.

Answer (score 2):

`char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);` expects its last argument to have type `const char *`

`temp` is a variable of type `char`.

So you're getting the error `Argument of type “char” is incompatible with parameter of type const char*`.

You could try something like this...

`strncat(number_string, &temp, 1)`

I usually favor something like...

`sprintf (buffer, "%s%c", number_string, temp)`

Comment: All this discussion overlooks the (painful) problem of buffer overflows of course.

Comment: I'm afraid your initial statement is incorrect: only the second argument of `strcat` has type `const char*`...  `snprintf` is much preferred over `sprintf` to avoid buffer overflows.  Your use of `strncat` is uncanny but not incorrect!

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your problem with types; it is a suggestion to tackle the problem in another way.

You want to fill a string with all numeric digits from the input string. There is no standard function to do this.

You could use `strcat`, but that function operates on strings, which must be zero-terminated. You could create a temporary string of two chars – one digit and one null-terminator – but that would be ineffective. `strcat` also requires you to ensure that you don't overflow the char buffer that you append to.

In cases like yours, it is usually easier to tackle the problem on a low level, where you create the char array yourself, one character at a time. For example, you can iterate through the input string with `i` and copy all digits to the number string by means of a second index, `j`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    size_t size = 12;
    char number[size];

    const char *input = "Alpha 123/Bravo 456/Charlie 789/Delta 007";
    int i, j;

    j = 0;
    for (i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (isdigit((unsigned char) input[i]) && j + 1 < size) {
            number[j++] = input[i];
        }
    }

    number[j] = '\0';
    puts(number);

    return 0;    
}
```

Note how the code keeps track of the characters in the number string and how it takes care not to overflow the buffer. The number string may be truncated, but it will always be null-terminated.

I've also used `input[i] != '\0'` to detect the end of the string (which is, by definition, the null terminator `'\0'`) instead of calling `strlen(input)`, which always starts looking for the terminator fro the beginning of the string.

Comment: Just two small issues: `input` should be `const char *` and `isdigit(input[i])` should be `isdigit((unsigned char)input[i])`

Comment: Yes, that sign issue of the `is...` macros always bugs me. The cast should really be part of the macro.

Comment: Not possible, because the macro accepts EOF as a valid argument.  The real fix for this issue is to make `char` unsigned by default.  The common compiler default to consider `char` signed by default creates inconsistencies in the language and with the standard library.  Try this: `if ('\200' != L'\200') printf("signed char has surprising side effecst!\n");`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- calling `strlen(input_string - 1)` most likely invokes undefined behaviour.  You probably meant `strlen(input_string) - 1` which would still cause the loop to run too far if `input_string` is an empty string;
- calling `strlen` for each iteration is inefficient anyway;
- calling `isdigit(temp)` is incorrect if `temp` is a `char` and `char` is signed by default;
- `strcat` cannot be used the way you call it;
- you should check for potential buffer overflow if all digits do not fit in the destination array.

Here is a much simpler function to extract all digits from the input_string:

```
char number_string[size];
int i, j;

for (i = j = 0; input_string[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    unsigned char uc = input_string[i];
    if (j < size - 1 && isdigit(uc)) {
        number_string[j++] = uc;
    }
}
number_string[j] = '\0';
```